# Making profit from Arduino

Tags: arduino-builder

I have been experimenting with Arduino for a couple of months, and, riding on the back of my 16 years as a high school science teacher (I am now back at university as a student), I can see a few potential improvements for existing science experiments in the high school teaching lab. My question is this: can I make packages based on Arduino and legally sell them to schools for a small profit? Since I’m no longer a teacher, I wouldn’t be using them myself, so I’d have to at least recoup my costs.

Comment: There are plenty of kits out there already.  What would make yours unique?  What would you do differently to market it to schools that other vendors aren't already doing?  Those are the questions you have to ask yourself and have the answers to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Arduino itself is open, and you can use it to make commercial products.

Note however, that for commercial products, a lot of additional requirements may be needed (regulations, safety, certifications), especially since it will be used in public places among (many) other people. You don't want students to be injured/die because of a badly designed device.

Not that I think you might not capable, but it might be something to keep in mind, that your project is maybe more than just creating some software and adding some packages and sell them.